# Boolean values list to integer in Python

Tags: python, lambda, filter, boolean, reduce

I'm having trouble with this lambdas syntax.
I'm trying to translate a list of booleans to an integer value, but I'm getting an error, I don't understand why.

Here is the code:

```
from functools import reduce

binary = [True, True, False, True]

L = list(range(len(binary)))      #Step 1
print(L)                          #[0, 1, 2, 3]
L = map(lambda a: 2**a, L)        #Step 2
print(L)                          #[1, 2, 4, 8]
L = zip(binary, L)                #Step 3
print(L)                          #[(True, 1),(True, 2),(False, 4),(True, 8)]
L = filter(lambda a, b: a, L)     #Step 4
print(L)                          #[(True, 1),(True, 2),(True, 8)] not sure
L = map(lambda a, b: b, L)        #Step 5
print(L)                          #?????
L = reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, L) #Final step 
print(L)                          #11
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/axel_/PycharmProjects/Python_Subject_Exam/19_new_exam_binary_list_translation.py", line 27, in <module>
    L = reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, L)
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
[0, 1, 2, 3]
<map object at 0x00000267FAFE5388>
<zip object at 0x00000267FAFE50C8>
<filter object at 0x00000267FAFE5248>
<map object at 0x00000267FAFE4EC8>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could anyone help me to debug?

Comment: `map` and `reduce` returns a generator in python3. So, you only need to cast `L` to a `list` when printing... like so: `print( list(L) )`

Comment: Got it @Anwarvic thanks for your response, but still I'm figuring why I can't perform the `reduce`

Comment: If you follow @Anwarvic's advice you will be able to see the output prior to the call to reduce. This might help you identify your issue.

Comment: Hello @Tim, actually I tried to cast `L` to a list since step #4 but I'm getting the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/axel_/PycharmProjects/Python_Subject_Exam/19_new_exam_binary_list_translation.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(list(L))
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'`

Comment: Your error is here `L = filter(lambda a, b: a, L)` filter takes a lambda with a *single* parameter. A much better option is to express this as `L = (b for a, b in L if a)` this is the generator expression version of `filter`.

Comment: Using a generator expression you can actually reduce this entire operation to `sum(2**i for i, b in enumerate(binary) if b)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem. I will write some comments in the code to help you understand:

```
from functools import reduce

binary = [True, True, False, True]
L = list(range(len(binary)))       #[0, 1, 2, 3]

L = map(lambda a: 2**a, L)         #[1, 2, 4, 8]

L = zip(binary, L)                 #[(True, 1), (True, 2), (False, 4), (True, 8)]

L = filter(lambda x: x[0], L)      #<--- an item from zip() is an ((unpacked)) tuple

L = map(lambda x: x[1], L)
L = reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, L)
print(L)                           #11
```

Comment: "cast your map object to list zip() expects iterable NOT a generator" this is bad advice a generator is iterable (so is a list).

Comment: yes, you're right. It was unnecessary. I've edited my code

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the challenges if you are new to using iterators.

The iterator is evaluated as each item is pulled off the iterator, this means that when you call reduce to combine the result all of the lambda expressions are evaluated at that time. In your example this is equivalent to the following expression:

```py
L = list(range(len(binary)))
L = reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, 
    map(lambda a, b: b, 
        filter(lambda a, b: a, 
            zip(binary, 
                map(lambda a: 2**a, L)
            )
        )
    )
)
print(L)
```

Confusing?

In your example the line `L = filter(lambda a, b: a, L)     #Step 4` has an error. A filter expression takes a callable expression that takes a *single* argument along with an iterable but because it is not evaluated to the end you receive a confusing error.

One approach (and a good one when debugging) is to wrap each step in a call to `list` to force the evaluation to occur on each line eg `L = list(filter(lambda a, b: a, L))`. This will make the location of the error more apparent.

Alternatively use a generator expression rather than `filter`/`map` eg:

```py
# filter (return odd numbers between 1 and 10)
result_a = filter(lambda a: a % 2, range(1, 11))
result b = (a for a in range(1, 11) if a % 2)

# map (return powers of 2)
result_a = map(lambda a: 2**a, range(11))
result_b = (2**a for a in range(11))
```

All of the results are the same but generator expressions have another trick, you can use tuple unpacking allowing for:

```py
result = (b for a, b in zip(binary, range(len(binary))) if a)
```

Further, Python has other builtins that can simplify the code even more.

Enumerate will return a counter plus each element from an iterable allowing the first 3 steps to be simplified to:

```py
# 1 step 1, 2 and 3 can be simplified with enumerate
L = ((i**2, b) for i, b in enumerate(L))
```

Next `sum` can be used to replace `reduce`, `sum` adds together all numerical values in an iterable:

```py
L = reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, L)
# is equivalent to
L = sum(L)
```

And putting it all together the entire sequence can be simplified to:

```py
L = sum(2**i for i, b in enumerate(binary) if b)
```

Hope that helps.